# e.preventDefault is not a function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, post

I am using React to make a form that will make a POST to MongoDB, what happens is that when I start trying to fill the form I get the following error:

```
e.preventDefault is not a function
```

TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
at handleChange

this is the code (in a summarized form), this is handleChange and handleSubmit:

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setProject({ ...project, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5001/client/projects", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(project),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    });

    const data = await res.json(project);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(project);
  };
```

and here is a small part of the form:

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Box width="50%">
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DatePicker
                    id="project_start"
                    name="project_start"
                    value={project.project_start}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    slotProps={{
                      textField: {
                        size: "small",
                        margin: "dense",
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                  <DatePicker
                    id="project_end"
                    name="project_end"
                    value={project.project_end}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    renderValue={(selected) => {
                      return [{ selected }];
                    }}
                    slotProps={{
                      textField: { size: "small", margin: "dense" },
                    }}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
                <TextField id="nombreP" margin="dense" size="small" />
                <FormControl size="small" sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                  <Select
                    id="encargadoP"
                    multiple
                    name="usersId"
                    value={project.usersId}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    MenuProps={MenuProps}
                    renderValue={(selected) => (
                      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}>
                        {selected.map((value) => (
                          <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                        ))}
                      </Box>
                    )}
                    sx={{ width: 205 }}
                  >
                    {data?.map(({ _id, name }) => (
                      <MenuItem key={_id} value={name}>
                        {name}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </Box>
            </Box>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant={"outlined"}
              size={"large"}
              sx={{
                width: 420,
                border: "1px solid white",
                m: "3rem 0 0 0",
                color: "white",
                borderRadius: "30px",
              }}
            >
              Agregar proyecto
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </form>
```

I am very grateful to everyone who can help me :)

Comment: Where/how do you call `handleSubmit`?  What is `e`?  Additionally, the stack trace identifies a function called `handleChange`.  Where is that?

Comment: in the onSubmit of a form: <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>. I had not put the code with the handleChange, sorry. I added it to the question

Comment: I'm [not able to replicate the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-forest-j8t9sl).  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  I suspect you've made a mistake or false assumption in your debugging.  Is the error happening in `handleSubmit` or in `handleChange`?  The stack trace says one thing, you say another.  If the problem is in `handleChange` then how is that function called and what is `e`?  Please make sure you are demonstrating the problem before asking.

Comment: How is `handleChange` called?

Comment: @David I left some of the code in the question

Comment: @Konrad the handleChange is in each of the form inputs

Comment: What is that `DatePicker`? Is that from a library? Why do you want to prevent default a change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onChange` callback for MUI's `DatePicker` is called with the new value as the first argument, not the event object.

Thus your code should be changed to something like this:

```js
const handleChange = (name, newVal) => {
    setProject({ ...project, [name]: newVal });
};
```

```
<DatePicker id="project_start" name="project_start" value={project.project_start}
      onChange={handleChange.bind(null, 'project_start')}/>
{ /* and so on for the other DatePickers ... */ }
```

Comment: Alternatively: `value => handleChange('project_start', value)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer <3 but I have another doubt, in the case of the Select, what would I have in the onChange? The only Select that is multiple is the one in the code I shared, the other Selects I have are to choose a single option.

Comment: @ValentinaLoaiza For Select, you do get the event object, so it would be: `onChange={e => handleChange('usersId', typeof e.target.value === 'string' ? e.target.value.split(',') : e.target.value)}`. The split part is only necessary for multiple selects.

Comment: thank u so much, u are the best <3

Comment: @Unmitigated Sorry to bother you at this time, but the TextField no longer shows me the text I'm typing, do I have to use a different handleChange? :c I would be very grateful if you could help me.